# ReactJS: Dragging element not working with onmousemove

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to make my own implementation of a drag element by creating a wrapper component that will allow a subcomponent to be dragged. But for some reason, only the first wrapped element can be drag.

```
class DraggableElement extends Component {

    draggable = false;

    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state = { transform: "translate(0px, 0px)" };

        window.onmousemove = (e)=>{
            this.log(`should component drag? = ${this.dragging}`);
            if(this.dragging){
                this.setState({
                    transform : `translate(${e.clientX}px, ${e.clientY}px)`
                });
            }
        };
    }


    log(message){
        console.log(`${this.props.id}: ${message}`);
    }


    onMouseDown(e){
        this.dragging = true;
        this.log(`is draggin? ${this.dragging}`);
    }

    onMouseUp(e){
        this.dragging = false;
        this.log("is not dragging");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                className="draggable-element"
                onMouseDown={(e)=> this.onMouseDown(e)}
                onMouseUp={(e)=> this.onMouseUp(e)}
                style={this.state}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The `Editor` component, where I place all the draggable components:

```
// imports
import DraggableElement from './DraggableElement';

class Editor extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <DraggableElement id="1">
                    <select></select>
                </DraggableElement>

                <DraggableElement id="2">
                    <select></select>
                </DraggableElement>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And here the css for the 'dragglable-element':

```
.draggable-element{
  border:solid 10px blue;
  position:absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And the `App.js`:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Editor></Editor>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the error. I should have used `window.addEventListener` instead of `window.onmousemove` since i was overriding the previous assingment of the callback.

I changed:

```
window.onmousemove = (e)=>{
        this.log(`should component drag? = ${this.dragging}`);
        if(this.dragging){
            this.setState({
                transform : `translate(${e.clientX}px, ${e.clientY}px)`
            });
        }
    };
```

To:

```
  window.addEventListener("mousemove",(e=>{
            this.log(`show component drag? = ${this.dragging}`);
            if(this.dragging){
                this.setState({
                    transform : `translate(${e.clientX}px, ${e.clientY}px)`
                });
            }

            e.preventDefault();
        }));
```

And its working now.